# Link to Python with MinGW

Tags: python, mingw

I wan't want to create a cross-plattform programm that embedds the python interpreter, and compile it with MinGW. But the Python Binary distribution provides no libraries for MinGW to link with (only `python32.lib` for Visual C++), and the Python Source package provides no support for compiling with MinGW.

I tried linking to `python32.lib` in Mingw with `-lpython32` but it still generates errors like:

```
main.cpp: undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
main.cpp: undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Finalize'
```

How do I link Python in MinGW? I really don't want to switch to using Visual C++.

Comment: Could it be that your problem was [using a 32 bit compiler to link against a 64 bit library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7938936/269126)? In addition, what you wrote is not correct. The Python distribution does provide libraries that can be used with MinGW (or any other C compiler). There's no requirement to use MSVC. But there is a requirement for matching 32 versus 64 bit architecture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With nm and dlltool from binutils, you should be able to rebuild the library for gcc:

```
echo EXPORTS > python32.def
nm python32.lib | grep " T _" | sed "s/.* T _//" >> python32.def
dlltool --input-def python32.def --dllname python32 --output-lib libpython32.a
```

python_test.c:

```c
#include "Python.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is',ctime(time())\n)");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -Wall -IC:\Python32\include -LC:\Python32\libs -o python_test.exe python_test.c -lpython32
```

Test:

```
C:\python_test.exe
Today is Mon Jul 18 08:50:53 2011
```

**Edit**: If you'd prefer to skip building this yourself on x64, you can download it for several versions from Christoph Gohlke's [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libpython).

**Edit**: Here's a Python version based on the existing function that's distributed in Tools/msi/msi.py:

```python
import subprocess
import warnings
import re

NM = 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-nm'
DLLTOOL = 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-dlltool'
EXPORT_PATTERN = r'^[_]{1,2}imp_(?P<export>.*) in python\d+\.dll'

def build_libpython(ver, nm=NM, dlltool=DLLTOOL,
                    export_pattern=EXPORT_PATTERN):
    pylib = 'python%s.lib' % ver
    pydef = 'python%s.def' % ver
    pydll = 'python%s.dll' % ver
    libpy = 'libpython%s.a' % ver
    warning = '%s failed - ' + '%s not built' % libpy
    match_export = re.compile(export_pattern).match
    cmd_nm = [nm, '-Cs', pylib]
    cmd_dlltool = [dlltool, 
                   '--dllname', pydll, 
                   '--def', pydef,
                   '--output-lib', libpy]
    with open(pydef, 'w') as f:
        f.write('LIBRARY %s\nEXPORTS\n' % pydll)
        p_nm = subprocess.Popen(cmd_nm, 
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                universal_newlines=True)
        for line in sorted(p_nm.stdout):
            m = match_export(line)
            if m:
                f.write(m.group('export') + '\n')
        if p_nm.wait() != 0:
            warnings.warn(warning % nm)
            return False
    if subprocess.call(cmd_dlltool) != 0:
        warnings.warn(warning % dlltool)
        return False
    return True
```

For example:

```python
import os
for n in (27, 33, 35):
    pylib = 'python%s.lib' % n
    if os.path.exists(pylib):
        build_libpython(n)
        pydef = 'python%s.def' % n            
        lc_def = sum(1 for line in open(pydef))
        libpy = 'libpython%s.a' % n
        lc_lib = sum(1 for line in os.popen('ar -t %s' % libpy))
        assert lc_def == lc_lib
```

Comment: nm didn't work, but i found a python32.def in the source package. But MinGW somehow complains that he can't find python3.lib (yes library search path is set :)).

Comment: ... that `libpython32.a` is not part of the most updated version 3.2.1 which was released 8 day ago. Guess i'll use 3.2.

Comment: This works for me in the case of a C main function, however, it does not work when I try to build a dll, which uses the -shared flag.  In that case I am back to the same error:

Comment: For me, with Python 2.7, this way of creating the .def file left out many methods whose names don't start with _ (e.g. `__imp_PyEval_CallFunction`, `__imp_PyInt_FromLong`) and I still got undefined reference errors. Using `gendef` as RMWChaos suggested solved the problem.

Comment: @lapis, I know you have a working solution already, but if you feel like experimenting, try the `build_libpython` function from my recent edit.

Answer (score 7):

Try this...

1. Download [gendef](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Extension/gendef/) for your version of mingw (32 or [64 bit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/gendef)), and in msys shell...
2. Run `gendef /c/windows/system32/python32.dll`
3. Run `dlltool -D python32.dll -d python32.def -l libpython32.a`
4. Copy `libpython32.a` to your `./python32/libs` directory.

If your `libpython32.a` file is 0 bytes, something went wrong. Double-check that you downloaded the correct version of gendef for your version of mingw/msys. If you're running a 64-bit build, you'll likely have to download the gendef binaries and compile yourself, but that's simple enough.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem if you try to build a shared DLL. If the Py_Initialize() call is an exported DLL routine, it wont link and you will still get

undefined reference to _imp__Py_Initialize

Answer (score 0):

EmbeddingPython.c

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_SetProgramName((wchar_t *)argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
        "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

and use gcc as following:

```
gcc EmbeddingPython.c -I C:\Python34\include -LC:/Python34/libs -lpython34 -o a.exe
```

and it works as we expected.

```
D:\>a.exe
Today is Fri Aug 29 15:14:04 2014
```

Comment: Most Windows builds of Python are built with MSVC, so the libraries will be incompatible with this solution if building with GCC. This will report a pile of "skipping incompatible" errors when searching for -lpython34, followed by a 'cannot find -lpython34'.