# MS VC linker (link.exe): Why no warning for 32/64 bit CPU architecture mismatch?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, linker-errors, lnk2019

(Update: As per Hans' suggestion, here's a [suggestion to improve `link.exe`'s behaviour](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2353877-have-link-exe-report-x86-x64-compatibility-errors-), and you can vote for it if you have an account over there.)

---

Okay, I'm a fool. In January I installed Oracle on my computer, Win7 Pro 64 Bit. I installed the 64 Bit version. Yesterday, using MSVC Express, I tried to compile and link a small test programm `oci1.c` against `oci.h` and `oci.lib`.

```
cl /nologo /c /I%ORACLE_HOME%\oci\include oci1.c
link /nologo oci1.obj /LIBPATH:%ORACLE_HOME%\oci\lib\msvc oci.lib
```

My attempts kept failing with [`LNK2019`, which means *unresolved external symbol 'symbol' referenced in function 'function'*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx). The symbol in question (`_OCIEnvCreate`) is, of course, provided by `oci.lib`, so the linker should be able to resolve it.

It finally dawned on me that it couldn't work because my compiler is 32 bit only, and the import library is 64 bit. If you're a fool and you don't know or remember, then you can see it using the `dumpbin` utility:

```
$ dumpbin /headers %ORACLE_HOME%\oci\lib\msvc\oci.lib | head
File Type: LIBRARY
FILE HEADER VALUES
        8664 machine (x64)

$ dumpbin /headers oci1.obj | head
File Type: COFF OBJECT
FILE HEADER VALUES
         14C machine (x86)
```

So far, so good. But I wasted some time and would like to avoid repeating that experience.

While not incorrect, the `LNK2019` error message doesn't lead you straight in the right direction. There's no warning that you're attempting to link binaries for different CPU architectures.

Note that when you specify the X64 architecture, you are alerted to the fact that you specified X86 binaries:

```
$ link /machine:x64 /nologo oci1.obj /LIBPATH:%ORACLE_HOME%\oci\lib\msvc oci.lib
oci1.obj : fatal error LNK1112:
Modul-Computertyp "X86" steht in Konflikt mit dem Zielcomputertyp "x64".
```

But there is no such precise warning when you specify the X86 architecture, explicitly or implicitly:

```
$ link /machine:x86 /nologo oci1.obj /LIBPATH:%ORACLE_HOME%\oci\lib\msvc oci.lib
oci1.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol
  "_OCIEnvCreate" in Funktion "_main".
oci1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 nicht aufgelöste externe Verweise.
```

I just found the [/VERBOSE switch to `link.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wdsk6as6.aspx), which when used hints that no symbols are found in my 64 bit `oci.lib`.

Are there other options you can turn on to make the linking process more, eh, fool-proof?

---

**Update**: As per Hans' answer, I ran `dumpbin` on a 32 bit import library, and the names appear as follows:

```
$ dumpbin /exports D:\Opt\MySQL5.5\lib\libmysql.lib
_load_defaults
_myodbc_remove_escape@8
_mysql_affected_rows@4
_mysql_autocommit@8
_mysql_change_user@16
_mysql_character_set_name@4
```

Whereas the names in the 64 bit OCI import library that I'm dealing with here appear undecorated:

```
OCIXmlDbFreeXmlCtx
OCIXmlDbInitXmlCtx
ORLRconNativeInt
ORLRvalNativeInt
OraCoreIsPhysicalRawFile
OraMemAlloc
```

[Wikipedia regarding X86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention):

> When compiling for the x64 architecture in a Windows context (whether
>   using Microsoft or non-Microsoft tools), there is only one calling
>   convention — the one described here, so that stdcall, thiscall, cdecl,
>   fastcall, etc., are now all one and the same.

Also relevant the [article on name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C_name_decoration_in_Microsoft_Windows).

Makes sense to me now. One and only calling convention, hence no name mangling necessary, hence no leading underscore as per `cdecl` when compiling for X86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it simply complains about the missing symbol *before* getting around to checking the binary compatibility.  That will commonly happen first, x64 symbols don't have the leading underscore since x64 doesn't have any calling conventions.  Unless you use Microsoft import libraries, they don't decorate the symbols at all.

But I very much agree, getting the compatibility error first would be much more productive.  No idea how hard that is to implement.  Ask the guys who know and can make it work like that, post a feature request to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of this issue; and so the undecorated names in the `dumpbin /exports oci.lib` output looked okay to me. Could you elaborate on how Microsoft import libraries may change the game here, which is what you seem to imply?

Comment: Microsoft import libraries simply have an undecorated name that is the same for x86 and x64.  That's done with a .def file, it renames the identifier name generated by the compiler.  It is not that commonly done, having the decoration actually catches mistakes, having a mismatch in calling convention.  But is easier for GetProcAddress().  And happens to help with this specific problem.