# Python.h on windows with MinGW

Tags: python, c, header, libraries

I have a issue when importing Python.h in a C code

```
No such file or directory
```

I m on windows 7 64 bits with codeblocks IDE MinGW compiler

please can someone help me with installing python c librarie?

Comment: May help: [Link to Python with MinGW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731100/link-to-python-with-mingw). Also: [How do I create Python extensions?](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Python_extensions)

Answer (score 1):

With WinPython and gcc:
add -I"[WinPythonFolder]\[python-ver.amd64]\include

eg:

```
 gcc read_wfm_wrap.c -I"C:\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\include"
```

Answer (score 0):

open Project -> Build Options -> Search Directories and add path where python.h resides

Comment: where is build option button?

Answer (score 0):

In code::blocks just go to the  `Project` tab.  Then you open `Build Options` > `Search Directories' and click`Add`.

You then browse to the directory of your python installation and select the `include` folder
(or copy-paste the `include` folder to your project folder and add that folder itself to the list).

Select not to keep relative path.

That definitely fixes the problem and a similar solution should be used for other IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `Python.h` and all the header files it includes in it resides in `include` folder of Python's installation directory. You could just copy either all the header files from Python's include folder `C:\Py\Anaconda3\include` to gcc|cl 's include folder (Mine looks like this, `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include`) or only to the point where header files dependencies are resolved.