# Embedding Python in C under Windows

Tags: python, c, windows, mingw, embedding

I want to compile a .c file containing a Header Python.h using minGW on Windows 10. My Goal is to embedd some pythoncode in C an this is just a little test for the compiling. 
My sourcefile looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <C:\Python27\include\Python.h>

int main() 
{
    printf("Hello World from C");

    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello World from Python!!!')");

    Py_Finalize();


    return 0; 
}
```

My makefile looks as follows:

```
all: HelloWorld.c
    gcc -Wall -I C:\Python27\include -L C:\Python27\libs  -o HelloWorld.exe HelloWorld.c -lpython27
```

So if I compile my source Code with this makefile I get the following error:

```
gcc -Wall -I C:\Python27\include -L C:\Python27\libs  -o HelloWorld.exe HelloWorld.c -lpython27
C:\Users\ga96dux\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUQs2pM.o:HelloWorld.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
C:\Users\ga96dux\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUQs2pM.o:HelloWorld.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `_imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
C:\Users\ga96dux\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUQs2pM.o:HelloWorld.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Finalize'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ï»¿all] Error 1
```

I´ve tried everything I could find in the Internet but it doesn't work, is there anything wrong with the makefile, are there any suggestions how to solve this Problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have Windows version of Python installed? It might be a problem with gcc not able to link properly to Windows dll's.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731100/link-to-python-with-mingw/11619481

Comment: OT, but you might want to consider doing this with *3.6* instead of *2.7*.

Comment: tried it with 3.6 but that didn´t work for me!