# How to fix"undefined reference to `_imp__Py_IsInitialized' Error when link to Python with MinGW

Tags: python, gcc, undefined-reference

How to fix"temp\ccSZ9gCR.o....undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize' Error?

I use MinGW to compile a c++ file, which includes `<python.h>`.

```
g++ -Ic:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include test.cpp
```

It returns the error `` temp\ccSZ9gCR.o....undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize' ``

How can I fix it?

p.s. ,I want to embed python in C++.At first,I guess I should use -I -L to add some directories to be included in.
I changed the g++ comand as this:

```
    g++ -Ic:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include -Lc:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\libs test.cpp
```

In libs directory, there are python3.lib and python37.lib files.
But I still got the same error result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I solved this problem by reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731100/link-to-python-with-mingw

1)Run gendef /c/windows/system32/python32.dll

2)Run dlltool -D python32.dll -d python32.def -l libpython32.a

3)Copy libpython32.a to your ./python32/libs directory.